# Correct way to get the instance of Application in android

Tags: android, applicationcontext

Which of these ways is more proper for getting the instance of Application

1. Initialise static field in Application.onCreate() and provide static access to it

   ```
   public class MyApplication extends Application {

       private static MyApplication sInstance;

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           sInstance = this;
       }

       public static MyApplication getInstance() {
           return MyApplication.sInstance;
       }
   }

   public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           MyApplication application = MyApplication.getInstance();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create static method which takes Context as param and cast that Context to MyApplication

   ```
   public class MyApplication extends Application {

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
       }

       public static MyApplication getInstance(Context context) {
           return ((MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext());
       }
   }

   public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           MyApplication application = MyApplication.getInstance(context);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I do not understand one thing here. If you really want a `Context` in `BroadcastReceiver`  then `onReceive(Context context,...)` already provide as a First Parameter. Use that one.

Comment: I've never seen way 2, but it doesn't make sense to me because if you have a Context, you can do getApplicationContext

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend method 3 if you **only** need the instance of the Application.

I would recommend method 1 if you had additional methods in your Application class because you can more clearly do

```
MyApplication.getInstance().foo();
```

Method 2 is just a shortcut for method 3, so I wouldn't recommend it.

---

All in all, it's a matter of preference. There is no one "correct" way because they'll all work.

Comment: Making context and application instance static is not a good way. This can leak memory.

Answer (score 2):

```
(getActivity().getApplication() as MyApplication)
```

This will return the instance of MyApplication